# Managing a TCP connection via Bunny in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bunny

We are moving towards creating a message queuing system in AWS. Our micro service will communicate with Rabbit MQ via Bunny. I can connect and publish to the exchange but the tcp connection drops out after certain amount of time (20 seconds I guess). Bunny tries to reconnect and it does reconnect successfully.

My question is as per rabbit mq doco, we should be using channels on a tcp connection rather than opening a new tcp everytime. What is the best way to manage one tcp connection in ROR ? Should I create one TCP per request ?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to keep the connection alive by setting `heartbeat_interval => 60` on bunny connection string. This kept the connection alive.